# Can't access web interface of wifi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

i have a home network 192.168.1.1/24. Inside this net there is a WiFi router and another network 192.168.0.1/24 under it.

I can't connect to any WiFi client and router from my home network.

I think that I must configure routes, but i don't know how.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to connect from and where are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Configuring a static route on .1.1 (for 192.168.0.0/24 via .1.2) would work, yes. However you still _should_ disable the double-NAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your “wifi router” performs NAT, you cannot gain access to individual clients connected to it. This is a so-called Double NAT scenario, which is obviously not desirable.

What you need to do:

1. Disconnect “wifi router” from the network.
2. Set its LAN IP address to something like 192.168.1.2. It should be in the 192.168.1.0/24 network and not conflict with anything.

   - Optionally disable WAN or set an invalid configuration
3. Disable the DHCP server on the “wifi router”.
4. Connect “wifi router” to the network, *using a LAN port*.
   That’s LAN (“real” router) to LAN (“wifi” router).

After that, all devices will reside in the same network (broadcast domain) and you can access “wifi router”’s configuration page at the IP address you set.

Comment: Thank you. I set ip manually, but i have no internet on Wifi clients anymore. So I have Zyxel Keenetic lite 2 and it worked on Wifi router mode. I switch to Wifi AP mode and all worked fine as I want.

Comment: If after following this guide you didn’t have network connectivity for wireless clients, you most likely missed step 4.